# How many people know that Harry owns an Invisibility Cloak?

Tags: harry-potter

Few names I can tell are Dumbledore, Ron, Hermione & Snape.

How many others know this fact? Does the entire Gryffindor know this? I highly doubt it because this would mean the information got spread into entire school.

Comment: What point in time are you referring to? Obviously the number will change dramatically as people find out.

Comment: @Richard During the entire canon. A good answer can highlight it for every book.

Comment: Done and done. Not the easiest of searches.

Comment: Now that you've put it on the Internet, *everybody* does...

Comment: @DarthWedgius Nah. I don't think Wizards know what Internet is. Also, electricity conflicts with magic.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

The following people are present when Harry puts on or takes off his Cloak, or are present when someone specifically makes reference to his possession of an invisibility cloak. I have attempted to preserve the order in which we (the reader) learn of *their* awareness:

### Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone:

- Ron
- Harry
- Dumbledore
- Peter Pettigrew (probably)
- Hermione
- Hagrid (probably)
- Neville (probably)

### Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets:

- Hagrid (definitely)

### Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban:

- Malfoy (probably)
- Peter Pettigrew (and by extension, probably Voldemort and his Death Eaters)
- Lupin
- Snape
- Sirius Black

### Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire:

- Barty Crouch Jr.
- Moaning Myrtle
- Peeves
- Filch
- Dobby

### Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix:

- Mad-Eye Moody
- Tonks
- Kingsley Shacklebolt
- Sturgis Podmore
- Hestia Jones
- Ginny Weasley
- Luna Lovegood

**Note that by the end of this book, all of the Order of the Phoenix appear to be aware of his cloak.**

### Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince:

- The Ministry of Magic (possibly)
- Mr Weasley
- Neville (definitely)
- Malfoy (definitely)
- Professor Slughorn
- The Fat Lady

### Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows:

- Dolohov (briefly, prior to memory erasure)
- Thorfinn Rowle (briefly, prior to memory erasure)
- Kreacher
- Mrs Cattermole
- Various Dementors
- Nagini (and by extension, definitely Voldemort and his Death Eaters)
- Griphook
- Travers (while under Imperio Curse)
- Bogrod (while under Imperio Curse)
- Various Death Eaters
- Aberforth Dumbledore
- Alecto Carrow
- Amycus Carrow
- Professor McGonagall
- Mrs Weasley
- Everyone involved in the Battle of Hogwarts

**Note that by the end of this book, all of the Death Eaters and everyone present at the Battle of Hogwarts are aware that Harry has an invisibility cloak.** By extension I think we can reasonably assume that the entire Wizarding World is aware.

Answer (score -3):

The invisibility cloak that Harry has was owned by his father before Harry got it. Only a few people knew that Harry's father had it (i.e. Lily, Sirius, and Dumbledore). It was then passed down to Harry in his first year and only Ron, Hermione, Dumbledore and Malfoy know about it until the 7th book. Then Malfoy tells all of the Death Eaters so by the end many people know about the cloak.

Comment: A lot more people than just Ron, Hermione, Dumbledore and Malfoy know about it before the 7th book.