# When did Draco learn that Harry has an invisibility cloak?

Tags: harry-potter, invisibility-cloak, draco-malfoy

I can't remember how this happened in the books, but in the Half-Blood Prince film's train scene, Draco's actions seem to make it very clear that he knew that Harry has an invisibility cloak. When did he learn of this?

Comment: Probably in Azkaban, definitely in HBP; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/85471/how-many-people-know-that-harry-owns-an-invisibility-cloak/85472#85472

Comment: Back in Prisoner of Azkaban, there was a scene of Harry using his cloak to taunt Draco and his friends. It would make sense that Draco either saw Harry un-cloak or made a point of trying to understand exactly what happened. Either way, it's reasonable he knew of the cloak not long after that incident, and therefore well before Half-Blood Prince.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

He was surprised to see Harry's disembodied head floating around in *Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban*. If he's got half a brain, he almost certainly worked out later that Harry was using an invisibility *cloak*, although there are other [spells and charms](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Invisibility_Spell) that could achieve much the same effect.

> Crabbe stumbled – and his huge, flat foot caught the hem of Harry’s
> Cloak. Harry felt a great tug, then the Cloak slid off his face.
>
> For a split second, Malfoy stared at him.
>
> ‘AAARGH!’ he yelled, pointing at Harry’s head. Then he turned tail and
> ran, at breakneck speed, back down the hill, Crabbe and Goyle behind
> him.
>
> Harry tugged the Cloak up again, but the damage was done.

We don't get proof positive until a couple of books later, in *Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince*.

> ‘Petrificus Totalus!’
>
> Without warning, Malfoy pointed his wand at Harry, who was instantly
> paralysed. As though in slow motion, he toppled out of the luggage
> rack and fell, with an agonising, floor-shaking crash, at Malfoy’s
> feet, the Invisibility Cloak trapped beneath him, his whole body
> revealed with his legs still curled absurdly into the cramped kneeling
> position. He couldn’t move a muscle; he could only gaze up at Malfoy,
> who smiled broadly.

Comment: Yep, great answer! @Valorum

Comment: @Slytherincess - I remember going through the books quite closely when I was putting together my answer for [How many people know that Harry owns an Invisibility Cloak?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/85472/20774)

Comment: The "when" part was probably after having a conversation with Snape about what he saw.